# For what values of $z$ is $f(z) = e^z$ real? Imaginary?

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

I feel like I might understand this already, but I just wanted to make sure. I said that $f(z)$ is real is $z$=any real number and $f(z)$ is imaginary if $z=rj$, where $r$ is any real number. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that $z\in\mathbb{C}$ can be expressed in terms of $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ by $z=x+iy$. It follows that $f(z)=e^z=e^{x+iy}=e^xe^{iy}$. From Euler's formula we know $e^{iy}=\cos y+i\sin y$ hence $f(z)=e^x\cos y+ie^x\sin y$. If $f(z)$ is pure real, then that means the imaginary part $e^x\sin y$ vanishes; similarly, if $f(z)$ is pure imaginary, then the real part $e^x\cos y$ vanishes.

We know $e^x>0$ so we can focus only on $\cos y,\sin y$. For what values do these guys vanish? Remember $y$ is real.

Comment: Care to clarify which claim? what is not true about it?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite.

Write $z=x+yi$. Then
$$e^z = e^{x+yi} = e^xe^{yi} = e^x(\cos y + i \sin y) = e^x \cos y + (e^x \sin y)i$$
So when is $e^z$ real? And when is it imaginary?